# How to position div underneath another div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using bootstraps grid system and on the top row i have three divs with a grid of 3 & 6 & 3

The left div(3) is used for links, so the height might change from time to time the center div(6) stays the same and the right div(3) stays also might change from time to time.

The issue I'm having is when i try to add another div of (6) underneath the original div(6) it stays below the other div(3) in the center. I can't seem to get it to sit nicely below this div(6)?

````
    <div class="row justify-content-left">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Left</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <p> Link </p>
                    <p> Link </p>
                    <p> Link </p>
                    <p> Link </p>
                    <p> Link </p>
                    <p> Link </p>
                    <p> Link </p>
                    <p> Link </p>

            </div>
        </div>     </div>



        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Center</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website URL" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div></div>


<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Right</div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <p> Link </p>
            <p> Link </p>
            <p> Link </p>
            <p> Link </p>
            <p> Link </p>
            <p> Link </p>
            <p> Link </p>
            <p> Link </p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>


<div class="row justify-content-center">

    <div class="col-md-6">.
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Underneath Center</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>

            </div>
        </div>    </div>
        </div></div> ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap 4.

You might need to specify a little more in depth your use case, but you might try just placing your additional content in your center (`.col-6`) column?

```html
<div class="row justify-content-left">

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Left</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Center</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website URL" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card mt-5">
            <div class="card-header">More Content in Center</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Right</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
                <p> Link </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that has helped a lot.

Comment: @Eric If you're satisfied with the answer, please click the check mark to mark it as the solution. :)